# Which distribution should I use for Naive Bayes algorithm(Gaussian or Rayleigh)? What to do with categorical data?

Tags: distributions, conditional-probability, naive-bayes

***I am predicting whether credit card application of an individual would be approved or not given his/her credentials.***

I have the following dataset:

[image]

The variable descriptions are as follows:
[image]

I need to calculate the posterior probability that what is the probability of a credit card getting accepted, provided its credentials are given:

$$P(accepted/data)$$

Doubts:

1) To calculate the posterior probability, I need to calculate:

$$P(age/accepted)$$

I see here that the age distribution follows Rayleigh distribution. ***So should I use Rayleigh distribution for probability calculation?***

[image]

If so, how should I find out the parameter sigma?

2) To calculate the posterior probability, I also need to calculate:

$$P(majorcards/accepted)$$

"majorcards" has the following distribution:

[image]

***What should I do in this case?***

3) To calculate the posterior probability, I need to calculate:

$$P(owner/accepted)$$

and

$$P(selfemp/accepted)$$

as well.

***Can the probability $P(owner/accepted)$ be calculated by***

dividing the number of people who are owner among the ones who are accepted by total no.of accepted people?